# How many paths of length 2 exist in the graph K11,12?

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

How many paths of length 2 exist in K11,12?

And how to find out how many paths of length 2 exist in Kx,y? (a general case)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>,</sub> is a [complete bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph), i.e. its + nodes can be divided into two distinct groups consisting of respectively  and  nodes, and its edges are all those that link two nodes that are not member of the same group.

There are  edges in that graph. Paths of size 2 either start and end in the first group, or start and end in the second group. When counting *directed* paths, we must divide by two to express that the direction of the path is not relevant. So the number of such paths is:

(−1)/2 + (−1)/2

...which is:

(+y−2)/2

For <sub>11,12</sub> this gives us 11⋅12(11+12−2)/2 such paths, which is 1386.